# Indentify line breaks in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to identify a cell has line breaks(not the menu bar cell option, actual multiple lines through alt+enter), and extract each line separatedely

I have tried both

```
InStr(str, "\n") < 0
```

and

```
Split(str, "\n")
```

But doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VBA is not C# (`"\n"`). Line breaks you'll find on: `vbCr` or `vbLf` or `vbCrLf` constants.

For further information, please see:
[vbCr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcr%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[vbLf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vblf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[vbCrLf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**[EDIT]**

Points to Mat's Mug answer! I forgot about `vbNewLine` constant.

Answer (score 13):

There are no escape sequences in VBA. Use the built-in `vbNewLine` constant instead for the equivalent:

```
hasLineBreaks = InStr(str, vbNewLine) > 0
```

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278800.aspx), `vbNewline` returns a *Platform-specific new line character; whichever is appropriate for current platform*, that is:

> Chr(13) + Chr(10) [on Windows] or, on the Macintosh, Chr(13)

So you don't need to work with ASCII character codes, or even with their [respective built-in constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37531236/1188513).

Except Excel will strip CR chars from cell and shape contents, and this has nothing to do with VBA (the CR chars would be stripped all the same and "\n" wouldn't work for correctly reading that Excel data in C#, Javascript, or Python either) and everything to do with the context of where the string came from.

To read "line breaks" in a string with the CR chars stripped, you need to look for *line feed* chars in the string (`vbLf`).

But if you *systematically* treat the *line feed* character as a line ending, you'll eventually run into problems (esp.cross-platform), because ASCII 10 all by itself isn't an actual line break on either platform, and you'll find ASCII 13 characters in strings you thought you had stripped line breaks from, and they'll still properly line-break on a Mac, but not on Windows.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have a Text in a text box on a sheet with a line break (I copied it from a text editor and there it had a CRLF line break). Now using:            Debug.Print InStr(Sheet1.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text, vbNewLine) > 0
          Returns False          
And The expression           Debug.Print InStr(Sheet1.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text, vblf) > 0
Returns True. So that means vbNewline is not found in the textbox, but vblf is found.

Comment: @blablubbb that is correct (and expected), I've edited this rather ancient answer to clarify. In short, you copied the CR char to your clipboard, but Excel stripped it before making the pasted string the text value of that shape, because CR has a special meaning for Excel. This answer addressed the escape sequence part and missed the part about the string coming from a worksheet cell, which probably explains why the OP gave the other answer the green checkmark ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Consider either:

```
Split(str, Chr(10))
```

or

```
Split(str, Chr(13))
```

You may need to try both if the data has been imported from external source.